# VS 2017 15.7.2 Manage Nuget Package error "The visual Studio component cache is out of datePlease restart Visual Studio"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

Manage Nuget Package is giving error "The visual Studio component cache is out of date (assembly: NuGet.Configuration, version=4.7.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf38). Please restart Visual Studio"

As shown below

1. Tried to delete everything from below, But Not helping.

   ```
    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
   ```
2. Uninstalled Visual studio and Installed again, still didn't help.
3. Cleared component cache as well , still not working

   ```
    %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ComponentModelCache
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Visual Studio 2017 to 15.7.3 resolved my issue.